# LevelDB --- Code in C++

Tags: c++, key-value, key-value-store, key-value-coding, leveldb

The below given code is taken from LevelDB. I am giving two blocks of code for better understanding. I am unable to understand what is happening.

ThreadState is a structure and I have written here to make it easy for the reader.

```
struct ThreadState {
     int tid;             // 0..n-1 when running in n threads
     Random rand;         // Has different seeds for different threads
     Stats stats;
     SharedState* shared;

     ThreadState(int index)
         : tid(index),
           rand(1000 + index) {
     }
  };
```

Is the marked code below an object instantiation of class Benchmark? What is happening in the marked code below?

```
    void Run() {
       PrintHeader();
       Open();

       const char* benchmarks = FLAGS_benchmarks;
       while (benchmarks != NULL) {
         {
           //code ommitted
         }

         // Reset parameters that may be overriddden bwlow

         ***void (Benchmark::*method)(ThreadState*) = NULL;*** // What does this code line mean? // Benchmark is a class.

         bool fresh_db = false;
         int num_threads = FLAGS_threads;

         if (name == Slice("fillseq")) {
           fresh_db = true;
           method = &Benchmark::WriteSeq;
         }
```

If required, I can give detailed implementation of Benchmark as well.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
void (Benchmark::*method)(ThreadState*) = NULL;
// What does this code line mean?
// Benchmark is a class.
```

The above is a pointer to a member function. Since member functions are not like regular functions (they can only be called on a valid object), you cannot take their address it the same way you would for a free function.

Therefore the above syntax is introduced. It is similar to a regular function pointer except the class specifier `Benchmark::`. This is essentially the type of the implicit `this` pointer.

In your case, `method` is a pointer to a member function that takes `ThreadState*` as a parameter, and has a `void` return type. The reason for using it is most probably to simplify the call. First, and based on various parameters, a member function is chosen to be called, and its "address" stored in `method`. After all the checks are done, there is only a single call to the chosen function via the pointer to member.

Incidentally, `&Benchmark::WriteSeq` is how the code obtains the "address" of the member function `WriteSeq`. You must use the address-of operator on the qualified function name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It did help me a lot. Only if life was as good as stackoverflow!!

Comment: @NewUser - Happy to help :)